# How to add transition to the height of the View on change in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

as you can see in the image, on clicking on Men the list of categories are shown. What I want is to add a transition or animate the increasing height. Also I want to rotate the arrow smoothly on showing the category list. Thanks.

here is the code of my component and also I have pasted the dummy data for the component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import HomeHeader from '../components/homeHeader';
import {categoryData} from '../components/categoriesData';

const Categories = ({navigation}) => {
  const [catState, setCatState] = useState({});
  const [subCatState, setSubCatState] = useState({});

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.categoryContainer}>
      <HomeHeader navigation={navigation} />
        {categoryData?.map(item => {
          return (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=>{setCatState({...catState,[item.gender]:catState[item.gender]===true?false:true})}}
                style={styles.categoryTitle}>
                <View style={styles.titleLeft}>
                  <Ionicons
                    style={{marginLeft: 5}}
                    name={item.genderIcon}
                    size={30}
                    color="grey"
                  />
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold',marginLeft:10}}>{item.gender}</Text>
                </View>
                <MaterialIcons
                  style={{marginRight: 8}}
                  name="keyboard-arrow-down"
                  size={15}
                  color="grey"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {item?.category?.map(value => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={()=>setSubCatState({...subCatState,[value.catId]:subCatState[value.catId]===true?false:true})}
                      style={catState[item.gender]? styles.categoryContent:styles.catContentClose}>
                      <Text style={{marginLeft: 8}}>{value.catName}</Text>
                      <MaterialIcons
                        style={{marginRight: 8}}
                        name="keyboard-arrow-down"
                        size={15}
                        color="grey"
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {value?.subCategory?.map(val => {
                      return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          onPress={console.log('')}
                          style={catState[item.gender] && subCatState[value.catId]? styles.categorySubContent:styles.subCatClose}>
                          <Text style={{marginLeft: 8}}>{val.subCatName}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      );
                    })}
                  </>
                );
              })}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  categoryTitle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#efdfbb',
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  titleLeft: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  categoryContent: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  catContentClose:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  categorySubContent: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
  },
  subCatClose:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 0,
  }
});

export default Categories;
```

the dummy data for the component

```
export const categoryData = [
  {
    gender: 'Men',
    genderIcon: 'ios-man',
    category: [
      {
        catName: 'topwear',
        catId: '11',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Shirts', subCatId: '011'},
          {subCatName: 'T-Shirts', subCatId: '012'},
          {subCatName: 'Sweaters', subCatId: '013'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'bottomwear',
        catId: '12',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Jeans', subCatId: '021'},
          {subCatName: 'Trousers', subCatId: '022'},
          {subCatName: 'Tracks', subCatId: '023'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'footwear',
        catId: '13',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Sneaker', subCatId: '031'},
          {subCatName: 'Brogues', subCatId: '032'},
          {subCatName: 'Flipflops', subCatId: '033'},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    gender: 'Women',
    genderIcon: 'ios-woman',
    category: [
      {
        catName: 'topwear',
        catId: '88',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Crop Tops', subCatId: '041'},
          {subCatName: 'T-Shirts', subCatId: '042'},
          {subCatName: 'Sweaters', subCatId: '043'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'bottomwear',
        catId: '124',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Jeans', subCatId: '044'},
          {subCatName: 'Skirts', subCatId: '045'},
          {subCatName: 'Shorts', subCatId: '046'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'footwear',
        catId: '134',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Sneaker', subCatId: '047'},
          {subCatName: 'Sandles', subCatId: '048'},
          {subCatName: 'Flipflops', subCatId: '049'},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    gender: 'Kids',
    genderIcon: 'ios-happy-outline',
    category: [
      {
        catName: 'topwear',
        catId: '110',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Shirts', subCatId: '051'},
          {subCatName: 'T-Shirts', subCatId: '052'},
          {subCatName: 'Sweaters', subCatId: '053'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'bottomwear',
        catId: '121',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Jeans', subCatId: '054'},
          {subCatName: 'Shorts', subCatId: '055'},
          {subCatName: 'Tracks', subCatId: '056'},
        ],
      },
      {
        catName: 'footwear',
        catId: '131',
        subCategory: [
          {subCatName: 'Sneaker', subCatId: '057'},
          {subCatName: 'Shoes', subCatId: '058'},
          {subCatName: 'Flipflops', subCatId: '059'},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[image]

Comment: You can achieve that behavior by using UIManager and LayoutAnimation, try checking [this](https://medium.com/@KPS250/layout-animations-in-react-native-c1bce624a843) article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this called [layout animation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation).

**simple example**
[image]

steps to do the above example:

```js
//you need to import 
import { LayoutAnimation, UIManager} from "react-native";
```

```js
//to work on Android you need to set the following flags via UIManager
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
  }
}
```

```js
//define height state to save height inside it
const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);
```

```js
//change height function
const changeHeight = (newHeight) => {
   LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
   setHeight(newHeight);
}
```

```js
//in render function
<TouchableOpacity
   style={{height : height}}
   onPress={() => changeHeight(300)}
>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

full example test snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@ahmed_gaber/layoutanimation) only (android & ios) not web

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { LayoutAnimation, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, UIManager, View } from "react-native";

if (
  Platform.OS === "android" &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental
) {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

const App = () => {

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(100);

  const changeHeight = (newHeight) => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    setHeight(newHeight);
  }


  return (
    <View style={{flex : 1, alignItems : "center", justifyContent : "center"}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{height : height, width : 300, backgroundColor : "red"}}
        onPress={() => changeHeight(height === 100 ? 300 : 100)}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```